# Loading a controller from a DLL outside of bin directory cannot find views within Areas folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razorengine

I have Areas within an MVC 4 application that contain Views and Content. I have written a `PreApplicationStartMethod` to be invoked to load the DLL containing the controllers for this area on application start:

```
public static class Initializer
    {
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            var AreasFolder = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Areas"));
            var PluginAssemblies = AreasFolder.GetFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach(var PluginAssembly in PluginAssemblies)
            {
                var Asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(PluginAssembly.FullName);
                BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly(Asm);
            }
        }
    }
```

This successfully loads the DLLs and everything works as I'd expect with one issue - Views cannot be found for the controllers that were loaded in a dll outside of the bin directory and I'm presented with the standard "The view 'x' or its master was not found or now view engines supports the searched locations..." however in the searched locations I can see the path to the view:

```
~/Areas/[Area Name]/Views/[Controller Name]/[View].cshtml
```

My thoughts are leading me to think that when the controller is mapping the tilde to a different location than what it would if the DLL was in the bin directory, but I'm not sure how best to diagnose.

I've tried moving the rest of the applications views into the Areas/Views folder to see if it was the *layout* that could not be resolved, and I've also tried copying the views out of the Areas folder into the root of the application to see if that worked, but both of these actions yielded the same exception as before.

What is interesting is if I have a broken reference on the view, I will get that exception message instead of the "can't find the views" exception, so it appears that MVC *is* finding the view but for some reason cannot render it??